# Import data to enterprise custom field/look up table

Tags: c#, ms-project

I have a problem. I want to import data from SQL/Excel to lookup table and let enterprise custom field to look it up.

I'm using Microsoft Project 2016 Professional/Online.

I've used C# samples to read tables and their entries. But I'm not able to add to the tables. Maybe someone has suggestions/samples for this kind of problem?

```
  SvcLookupTable.LookupTableDataSet lutDs = new SvcLookupTable.LookupTableDataSet();
        LookupEntryCreationInformation creationInfo = new LookupEntryCreationInformation();
        LookupEntryValue entryValue = new LookupEntryValue();
        Guid entryTableGuid = new Guid("417552b5-7877-e711-80ce-00155d40cd19");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------Lookup Tables---------------");
        LookupTableCollection lookupTables = projContext.LookupTables;
        projContext.Load(lookupTables);
        projContext.ExecuteQuery();

        entryValue.TextValue = "ITS";
        creationInfo.Value = entryValue;
        creationInfo.Id = entryTableGuid;

        LookupTableCollection lookupTablesColl = projContext.LookupTables;
        projContext.Load(lookupTables);
        projContext.ExecuteQuery();
        int numTables = projContext.LookupTables.Count;
        LookupTable lookTable = lookupTables[numTables-1];



        Guid rowGuid = new Guid();

        foreach (Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.LookupTable lt in lookupTables)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(lt.Name + " {" + lt.Id + "}");


            ImportLookupTable importTable = new ImportLookupTable();
            importTable.AddLookupTableValues(lutDs, rowGuid, rowGuid,"ITS","Skyr");
            projContext.Load(lt.Entries);
            projContext.ExecuteQuery();

             foreach (LookupEntry entry in lt.Entries)
             {

                 Console.WriteLine("    " + entry.FullValue + " {" + entry.Id + "}");

             }
        }
```

Comment: Tried code write here.

Comment: I've used this code https://github.com/rlv-dan/Tutorial-code/tree/master/Working%20with%20Custom%20Enterprise%20Fields%20in%20MS%20Project%20Online